# Open new Finder window using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How can I open a new window of Finder in AppleScript?  I am using an if else statement to open a window. I tried an `Osascript` command but it gave me a syntax error.  The code is below:

```
if the button returned of the result is "Sleep" then
    tell app "Finder" to go to sleep
if the button returned of the result is "Open Finder" then
    osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to open new window'
else
    display dialog current time
end if
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
```

Comment: Nicely done; there are two quirks as of OSX 10.11.4. (a) Curiously, windows created this way don't show up in the `Window` menu. (b) The `target` (i.e., the location) of the new window is always the device view of the entire computer, irrespective of what's configured in Finder's preferences. Furthermore, it seems that `with properties { target: ... }` is ignored - do you know of a way to specify the target location (other than setting it _later_, which is visually disruptive)?

Answer (score -1):

My Alfred Workflow script:

```
on alfred_script(q)
    tell application "Finder"
        make new Finder window
    end tell
end alfred_script
```