# Opening multiple windows with Applescript

Tags: windows, shell, applescript

I am trying to write an Applescript to open three VLC windows in different screen positions. The script opens three instances of VLC but has them one on top of the other (using the position for window 1). Help with the code appreciated:

```
do shell script "open -n /Applications/Video/VLC.app"
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    set bounds of first window of application "VLC" to {13, 36, 790, 519}
end tell

do shell script "open -n /Applications/Video/VLC.app"
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    set bounds of second window of application "VLC" to {13, 544, 790, 1027}
end tell

do shell script "open -n /Applications/Video/VLC.app"
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    set bounds of third window of application "VLC" to {13, 1043, 790, 1526}
end tell
```

Comment: What happens if you just create one or two instances of VLC and then, later, in a separate piece of Applescript you change a single window size to something massively different? Does that work? Is your Applecsript actually ever really targeting the correct app?

Comment: There are two problems. First, you have three instances of VLC which only have one window each. Second, there are multiple "VLC" applications running, so you can't address them by name. You'd have to get their pids with something like this: `tell application "System Events" to set {procesList, pidList} to the {name, unix id} of (every process whose name contains "VLC")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@khagler's comment provides the right pointer: the VLC instances must be distinguished by their PIDs (process IDs; called `unix id` in AppleScript) in the `System Events` context.

The code below should do what you want, arrived at after much toil and trouble -- par for the [AppleScript obstacle] course. One obstacle was that the VLC instances' main windows do not get created right away.

The comments provide more details.

Note that because user-interface elements are programmatically manipulated, the application running your script must be granted [assistive access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914) for security reasons.

Note that I'm starting the instances with `do shell script "open -na VLC.app"`, relying on the location of the app being known to Launch services (should that not work for some reason, revert to your method of specifying the full path).

```applescript
# Specify the desired window bounds.
# !! In the "System Events" context, windows do not 
# !! have `bounds` properties, but separate `position` and
# !! `size` properties.
set WIN_POSITIONS to {{13, 36}, {13, 544}, {13, 1043}}
set WIN_SIZES to {{790, 519}, {790, 519}, {790, 519}}

# Launch the VLC instances.
repeat with i from 1 to count of WIN_POSITIONS
    do shell script "open -na VLC.app"
end repeat

# Note:
# Instance-specific manipulation must
# be performed in the "System Events" context, because
# we must distinguish the VLC instances by their
# PIDs (process IDs; called `unix id` in AppleScript).
tell application "System Events"

    # Get the PIDs (process IDs) of all VLC instances.
    set vlcPids to get the unix id of every process whose name is "VLC"

    # Loop over all instance PIDs.
    # !! It is imperative to *continue* to use object specifiers
    # !! with *filters based on the PID* so as to ensure that the
    # !! individual instances are targeted.
    # !! Attempting to store references to these instances in
    # !! variables fails subtly, as evidenced by the "Events"
    # !! tab in AppleScript editor later showing the non-specific
    # !! process "VLC" of application "System Events" specifiers.
    set winNdx to 1
    repeat with vlcPid in vlcPids

        # WAIT for each instance to create its main window, wich
        # sadly, is not available right away.
        # Once created, position it.
        set haveWin to false
        tell (first process whose unix id is vlcPid)
            repeat with i from 1 to 25 # times out after 25 * .2 == 5 secs.
                if (count of windows of it) > 0 then
                    set haveWin to true
                    tell front window of it
                        # !! In the "System Events" context, windows do not 
                        # !! have `bounds` properties, but separate `position` and
                        # !! `size` properties.
                        set position to item winNdx of WIN_POSITIONS
                        set size to item winNdx of WIN_SIZES
                    end tell
                    exit repeat
                end if
                delay 0.2 # no window yet; sleep some and try again
            end repeat
        end tell
        if not haveWin then error "VLC instance " & vlcPid & " unexpectedly did not create a window within the timeout period."

        set winNdx to winNdx + 1
    end repeat

end tell
```

---

How to make this work with **Finder**:

Targeting Finder changes the approach for two reasons:

- there's only *one* Finder instance.
- you cannot open multiple *windows* with `open -na Finder.app`; thankfully, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189333/45375) shows how to do it (see the comments there for quirks).

Note that the following blindly opens *additional* Finder windows.

```
set WIN_POSITIONS to {{13, 36}, {13, 544}, {13, 1043}}
set WIN_SIZES to {{790, 519}, {790, 519}, {790, 519}}

# Sample target locations for the Finder windows.
# Note the use of the "System Events" context to faciliate use of
# POSIX-style *input* paths; note, however, that the paths are
# *stored* as HFS paths so that Finder accepts them.
tell application "System Events"
    set WIN_TARGETS to {¬
        path of desktop folder, ¬
        path of folder "~/Downloads", ¬
        path of folder "/Library/Audio"}
end tell

set winCount to count of WIN_POSITIONS

# Launch the Finder windows.
tell application "Finder"
    # Create the windows in reverse orders.
    repeat with i from winCount to 1 by -1
        set newWin to make new Finder window
        set target of newWin to item i of WIN_TARGETS
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "System Events"

    set i to 1
    repeat with i from 1 to winCount

        tell window i of application process "Finder"
            # !! In the "System Events" context, windows do not 
            # !! have `bounds` properties, but separate `position` and
            # !! `size` properties.
            set position to item i of WIN_POSITIONS
            set size to item i of WIN_SIZES
        end tell

    end repeat

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! Only thing that bother me is WIN_TARGETS, how can I add downloads directory? Or some custom path..

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the internet and much trial & error I have found this works well providing you allow the AppleScript Editor (or automator or your own app, whichever you are using) to control your computer under `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility` (OS X 10.9 Mavericks). The first time you run the script/app you'll be prompted to change the setting. After granting access, the second time you run the script/app the windows will be re-positioned.

```
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app /path/to/first/file" --edit path
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app /path/to/second/file" --edit path

    delay 3 --wait 3s for VLC to open files, increase if necessary

    tell application "System Events"
        set pidList to the unix id of (every process whose name contains "VLC")

        tell (first process whose unix id is item 1 of pidList)
            set the position of the front window to {0, 22} --edit {x,y}
        end tell

        tell (first process whose unix id is item 2 of pidList)
            set the position of the front window to {640, 22} --edit {x,y}
        end tell
    end tell
```

It's not as clever as [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952484/631373) but, as someone who is new to AppleScript, I could understand what's going on.

Comment: I can see how my answer is not easy to understand, but its complexity is required if you want _robustness_: my answer does NOT rely on hard-coded delays (and application paths). Believe me, I _wish_ this extra complexity were not needed, but it is. AppleScript has many, many subtle pitfalls.

Comment: The more I look at your script the more I learn and the more I can appreciate why your answer is better. I'm using my quick & dirty script to open two webcam streams that don't change and I have to hard code the window positions anyway so it's enough for my purposes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but finally used the @mklement0 solution and it works perfectly. Many thanks to all who took some trouble to figure out the solution to my problem. if you are ever near Ascot in the UK I owe you a beer!!