# How can I open multiple finder windows at the same time with apple script?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out how to open multiple finder windows at the same time; like opening several at a time.

Comment: The [same way you open one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21188431/62576) except you do it like four more times or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Arbitrary example:

```
 tell application "Finder" to open (every folder of home whose name starts with "Do")
```

See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show your existing code.